# Simple SQL statement

Tags: sql

I've been over-thinking this too much. Let's say I have a table TEST(refnum VARCHAR(5))

```
    |refnum|
    --------
    | 12345|
    | 56873|
    | 63423|
    | 12345|
    | 56873|
    | 12345|
```

I want my "view" to look something along the lines of this

```
    |refnum| count|
    ---------------
    | 12345|   3  |
    | 56873|   2  |
```

So the requirements are that the count for each refnum has to be > 1.
I'm having a little trouble wrapping my head around this one. Thank you in advance for the help.